# Why do i get this weird error when i try to run my bot? (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py

This is the code I have in my discord bot:

```py
import interactions
import discord
import os
token = os.getenv('token')
bot = interactions.Client(token)

@bot.command(
  name='embed',
  description='Create an embed',
  scope=1018631100773437612,
  options = [
    interactions.Option(
      type=interactions.OptionType.STRING,
      name='Title',
      description='The title of the embed',
      required=True
    ),
    interactions.Option(
      type=interactions.OptionType.STRING,
      name='Content',
      description='The content of the embed',
      required=True
    ),
    interactions.Option(
      type=interactions.OptionType.STRING,
      name='Image (url)',
      description='The imaged used in the embed (it has to be a url example: https://images.hindustantimes.com/rf/image_size_960x540/HT/p2/2017/09/12/Pictures/monkey-selfie_f82c8020-977d-11e7-9cb6-5fa30af43469.jpg',
      required=False
    ),
    interactions.Option(
      type=interactions.OptionType.STRING,
      name='Url',
      description='The url of the embed',
      required=False
    ),
    interactions.Option(
      type=interactions.OptionType.CHANNEL,
      name='Channel',
      description='The channel that the message will be in',
      required=True
    )
  ]
)

async def test(ctx: interactions.CommandContext, Title:str, Content:str, Channel:str, Thumbnail:str, url:str):
  embed = discord.Embed(
    title=Title,
    description=Content,
  )
  if url != None:
    embed.url = url
  if Thumbnail != None:
    embed.set_thumbnail(Thumbnail)
  await ctx.send(channel=Channel, embeds=embed)


bot.start()
```

Whenever I run my bot, I get this error:

```py
Could not prepare the client:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/botforofficial/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/interactions/client/bot.py", line 377, in _ready
    self.__resolve_commands()
  File "/home/runner/botforofficial/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/interactions/client/bot.py", line 471, in __resolve_commands
    self.__check_command(
  File "/home/runner/botforofficial/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/interactions/client/bot.py", line 899, in __check_command
    __check_options(_option, _opt_names)
  File "/home/runner/botforofficial/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/interactions/client/bot.py", line 803, in __check_options
    raise LibraryException(
interactions.api.error.LibraryException: An error occurred:
The option name does not match the regex for valid names ('^[a-z0-9_-]{1,32}$'), with code '11' and severity '0'
```

I really don't know what's causing this, whenever I look at tutorials, they never have this error.
The error doesn't tell me the line where the problem is, and I don't understand it at all

Comment: This doesn't look like discord.py code. What library are you using? Nextcord? PyCord?

Comment: black-box-answer. Error says validation on names - it must be a string with lower case / numeric characters also allowing -/_. Try changing your name values in the command as per the regex support!

Comment: if error doesn't show which line makes problem then you can still use `print(some_text)` after every line to see which line will be displayed. You may also remove elements (one-by-one) to see when it will work correctly - and this way you can also see which element makes problem.

Comment: @Kelo, i'm using interactions.py

Answer (score 0):

name='Image (url)'
There shouldn't be any blank space here.

name = 'Image(url)'

Answer (score -1):

The regex given suggests that you cannot have an option with the name `Image (url)`, specifically the brackets, try something like `Image URL`

Comment: doesnt work, imade it Thumbnail URL and it still gives me the error